# Создание дубликатов контрагентов

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Столкнулись с ситуацией дублирования контрагентов при создании продаж через розничное приложение. Я подозреваю, что дело в следующем: В качестве программы лояльности мы используем сайт интернет-магазина. Соответственно на нём регистрируются пользователи и оформляют заказы. Между сайтом и "Моим складом" происходит обмен совершенными заказами, если я правильно понимаю, то во время этого обмена происходит создание контрагентов на стороне "Моего склада" (которых ещё не  было). В настройках программы лояльности стоит галочка "Искать покупателей в системе лояльности"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда происходит поиск покупателя на сайте, то в соответствии с документацией возвращаем данные такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот тут скорее всего и возникает ситуация с дублированием. Уникальный идентификатор покупателя в системе лояльности в формате GUID должен совпадать с идентификатором покупателя в "Моем Складе"? Если да, то получается, что для корректной работы нужно время от времени синхронизировать контрагентов из моего склада с пользователями на нашем сайте и тогда вопрос какой из идентификаторов использовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для вставки изображений используйте, пожалуйста, кнопку «изображение».

Answer (score 0):

В качестве идентификатора КА используется id(формат UUID). accountId - это идентификатор вашего аккаунта(учетной записи) в МС

Comment: Получается идентификатор КА в программе лояльности всё-таки должен совпадать с его идентификатором в Моём Складе?